# Multiple lines mapped to the same colour ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a series of different studies I would like to compare on a line plot using ggplot, coloured by study, each of which contains several samples. The output graph I would like is a line plot of many lines, coloured by study such that each colour has several lines associated with it.

My data is 'wide' so I have gathered it into long form in order to use ggplot. A sample of my original data is:

```
  Element Robinson Robinson.1      Price       Gale     Gale.1
1       1     17.5       25.2       23.3      27.15      25.92
2       2     15.0       20.8       18.7      21.76      20.39
3       3     11.8       15.4       14.8      15.77      14.97
4       4     10.2       13.5       12.1         NA         NA
5       5      8.0       11.4        9.7      10.91      10.33
6       6      8.8       11.4        9.7      10.33       9.87
```

(This is structured to show the different categories, I can provide a dput version of my whole dataset if need be but it is quite long)

My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Reshaping data into long form 
df <- alldata %>%
  select(Element, c(2:87)) %>%
  gather(key= "Analysis", value = "value", -Element)

#Adding a new column based on study name
df$Study <-
  ifelse(grepl("Robinson",df$Analysis)==TRUE,"Robinson",
         ifelse(grepl("MI",df$Analysis)==TRUE,"MI",
                ifelse(grepl("Price",df$Analysis)==TRUE,"Price",
                       ifelse(grepl("Gale",df$Analysis)==TRUE,"Gale",
                              "Other"))))

#Plotting making sure to interpolate between gaps
ggplot(df[!is.na(df$value),], aes(x=Element, y = value))+
  geom_line(aes(color=Analysis),size=1, show.legend=FALSE)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

Reshaping the data gives me a long data frame with three columns: 'Element', 'Analysis' and 'Study'. 'Analysis' gives each sample from a study a unique name (e.g. Robinson1,Robinson2) and 'Sample' extracts the study from this.

My problem is, when I use 'Analysis' to map the colours in geom_line, I get the correct lines which each have a different colour - this is not what I want.
 However, when I use 'Study', the lines collapse into a zigzag pattern like this. The plots are here:

[image: plot 1]

[image: plot2]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem such that I get sets of lines with the same colour (halfway between these two plots)?

Comment: try `aes(group = Analysis, color = Study)`. `group` tells ggplot to split your data into separate lines by that variable without changing the appearance

Comment: As a side note, you may want to check out `case_when` from the dplyr package. It provides a neater, more readable alternative to nested `ifelse` statements.